# Infopath form does not apply changes in client machines

Tags: infopath

Our client asked me to add few combo boxes on his Infopath form.
I added them, but when I publish it I can see the changes on my machine but when the client tries to open the form they still see the old form?

Answer (score 0):

Is the form being published directly to the document library or to the server?

If it was directly to the library, you may need to relink the files to the new template.

Also, check in InfoPath Designer that On Version Upgrade is set to Automatically Upgrade Existing Forms (Tools -> Options -> Versioning)